# How to display Custom Attribute in Registration Form

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, custom-attributes

I wont to display custom drop down in customer form,

my sql.php

```
    $installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "how",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "How did you find us?",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "find/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions14353298130",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "Please select",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "how");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

my model.php

```
 class Irvas_Find_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Source_Customeroptions14353298130 extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Facebook"),
                    "value" =>  1
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Twitter"),
                    "value" =>  2
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Blog"),
                    "value" =>  3
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Google"),
                    "value" =>  4
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Friend referral"),
                    "value" =>  5
                ),

            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option["value"] == $value) {
                return $option["label"];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Column(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColums()
    {
        $columns = array();
        $columns[$this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode()] = array(
            "type"      => "tinyint(1)",
            "unsigned"  => false,
            "is_null"   => true,
            "default"   => null,
            "extra"     => null
        );

        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Indexes(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatIndexes()
    {
        $indexes = array();

        $index = "IDX_" . strtoupper($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        $indexes[$index] = array(
            "type"      => "index",
            "fields"    => array($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode())
        );

        return $indexes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Select For Flat Attribute update
     *
     * @param int $store
     * @return Varien_Db_Select|null
     */
    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel("eav/entity_attribute")
            ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
    }
}
```

I have tried in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` with this code

```
   <?php  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer','how'); ?>
    <label for="irvas_find" class="<?php if($attribute->getIsRequired() == true){?>required<?php } ?>"><?php if($attribute->getIsRequired() == true){?><em>*</em><?php } ?><?php echo $this->__('How did you find us?') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
<select name="how" id="how" class="<?php if($attribute->getIsRequired() == true){?>required-entry<?php } ?>">
<?php
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach($options as $option){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $option['value']?>" >
<?php echo $this->__($option['label']); ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>   
</div>
```

but I get `"Source model "" not found for attribute "irvas_find"`.
Thank in advance.

EDIT: config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Irvas_Find>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Irvas_Find>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <find>
        <class>Irvas_Find_Helper</class>
      </find>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <find>
        <class>Irvas_Find_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>find_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </find>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1435329813_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Irvas_Find</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1435329813_setup>
      <customerattribute1435329813_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1435329813_write>
      <customerattribute1435329813_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1435329813_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: You defined `find/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions14353246950` as the source model for your attribute. Does this model class exist?

Comment: That is the name of the first file in question. Inside file there is no class do I need it?

Comment: Ok, missed that! How is your namespace defined in your extension? specifically, the namespace definition for yoru models. is 'find' correct? If unsure, just post your config.xml contents.

Comment: I solved this. Was mistake with my model. Thank you for your answers you helped me to understend how this works.